# Is it possible to run JavaScript code before Meta refresh

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

All the while, we are using this realiable website redirection HTML/JavaScript code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=https://www.nosuchwebsite.com">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "https://www.nosuchwebsite.com"
        </script>
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Note: don't tell people to `click` the link, just tell them that it is a link. -->
        If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href='https://www.nosuchwebsite.com'>nosuchwebsite</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, we would like to have Google Analytics tracking code executed, before redirection.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

I realize, meta "refresh" may execute earlier than JavaScript tracking code. I was wondering, whether is there any way to make Google Analytics tracking code, to run before meta "refresh"

Answer (score 2):

### Solution for long scripts

We don't want to specify seconds if script is going to take quite a while and we ain't sure how long.

So the idea is to get the URL to redirect to from the meta like and redirect to it,

1. Stop refresh,

```
window.stop();
```

2. Do you script stuff
3. Finally get URL from meta and redirect to it.

```
window.location = document.querySelector( '[http-equiv="refresh"]' ).content.split( 'url=' )[1];
```

#### Here's an example

```js
// STEP 1: Stop currect redirection
window.stop();

// STEP 2: Do your script stuff
// promise? async/await? Do wtf you want.
const msgEl = document.getElementById( 'messages' );
const addMsg = msg => msgEl.innerHTML += msg + '<br>';
setTimeout( () => addMsg( 'Let me at least do my nails.' ), 1000 );
setTimeout( () => addMsg( 'Aah, I\'m having a bad hair day :(' ), 2000 );
setTimeout( () => addMsg( 'Almost done...' ), 3000 );
setTimeout( () => addMsg( 'Ok, just a (three) second(s)...' ), 4000 );
setTimeout( () => {
  addMsg( 'Redirecting...' );
  // STEP 3: Redirect, Finally done with every we wanted to do.
  window.location = document.querySelector( '[http-equiv="refresh"]' ).content.split( 'url=' )[1];
}, 7000 );
```

```css
/* Arbitrary CSS for presentation purposes only */

p, h3, small {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 2
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

code {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<!-- Resides somewhere inside <head> tag. -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https:///google.com/">

<!-- Arbitrary html for illustration -->
<h3>
Please wait while you are redirected with the mighty <code>meta refresh</code>.
</h3>

<p id='messages'></p>

<small><b>Spoiler:</b> Redirection will be stopped even though <code>meta[http-equiv="refresh"]</code> refreshes in 0 seconds.</small>
```

Comment: how is this implemented in an HTML file? I don't understand how the proposed HTML triggers the JS code.  Where does the JS code live?  And why the need for the CSS?

Comment: JS code could be anywhere in your HTML within <script> tags or in a separate JS file. Key part is to stop the refresh with `window.stop()` then carry one with your script stuff as needed. Finally redirect to the URL from meta tag.

Comment: CSS and HTML stuff is just for presentation. Key parts are __stopping the refresh__ and then **redirecting ourselves** when we are done with everything.

Comment: what guarantees that the javascript code runs before refresh to stop the redirection?  Is it just that the http-equiv has a 1 second wait?  Does it work if that's set to 0?  If not, then I think this is effectively equivalent to other posted solutions, it's just a little more reliable because you are stopping redirection, but you still need to get there before the http-equiv in <head> is executed.

Comment: It does :) Even if it is 0 ;)

Comment: Edited the answer to show 0 second refresh.

Comment: I'm going to award the bounty to this answer because it generally pushed me in the right direction.  Didn't 100% work, but it could have been because I was using Plausible and not Google Analytics.  Anyways, I'll separately post the final solution I landed on which works really nicely with Plausible.

Answer (score 1):

What about if you add the redirection inside Google Analytics script like below via HTML JavaScript DOM?

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

document.getElementById("metaTag").innerHTML='<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=https://www.nosuchwebsite.com">'
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta id="metaTag">
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Note: don't tell people to `click` the link, just tell them that it is a link. -->
        If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href='https://www.nosuchwebsite.com'>nosuchwebsite</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Per the bounty comments (and in the spirit of what the OP is asking for), the solution should use `http-equiv="refresh"`

Comment: @Suraj Oh I'm sorry. I forgot that meta part. I have edited my answer just now. Will it applicable now?

Comment: So in this approach the http-equiv is dynamically inserted?  If so, clever!  I think this might interfere with Google and other search engines' ability to determine that a page has been moved?

Comment: @Suraj https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/javascript/javascript-seo-basics#:~:text=Googlebot%20supports%20web%20components,at%20the%20rendered%20HTML. I think there have the answer for your question. As I guess, it won't affect to SEO because Googlebot and others can go with the rendered HTML content :)

Comment: Thanks!  Will test and see if it works.  I'm actually using Plausible Analytics instead of Google, but the solution should be the same.  Will report back in a day or two.

Comment: @Suraj I hope it will be so in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply increase the number of seconds for meta refresh command and it will wait for that long before redirecting to the new page. That will allow your JavaScript to execute meanwhile.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=https://www.nosuchwebsite.com">
                                    ^
```

can be

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=https://www.nosuchwebsite.com">
```

Comment: But. Is it safe and reliable enough? We are just making assumption that, after 3 seconds, JavaScript will finished executed?

Comment: 3 Seconds are tooooooooooooooooooooo long for a Google script to load, much more than enough. But you can of course increase the duration if you notice that its not enough

Answer (score 0):

Or don't use meta refresh and use Javascript refresh and have the meta refresh in a `<noscript>` block for good measure, as when Javascript is disabled the Analytics won't work anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works with Plausible (send event to Plausible before redirecting)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url="[TARGET_URL_HERE]">
        <link rel="canonical" href="[TARGET_URL_HERE]" />
        <script data-domain="[SOURCE_DOMAIN_HERE]" src="https://plausible.io/js/script.manual.js"></script>
        <script src="plausible-redirect.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            The page been moved to <a href=[TARGET_URL_HERE]</a>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**plausible-redirect.js**

```
// We would like to record a pageview with Plausible before redirecting so that we can capture data such as the referrer, search terms, etc.
// After the redirect, Plausible records the pageview for the target domain with the old domain
// as the referrer - it's all lumped together without any visibility into the true referral data.
// This is the best approach we could come up with in collaboration with Plausible support and a bounty
// that was added to this StackOverflow question:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205850/is-it-possible-to-run-javascript-code-before-meta-refresh
// The page initiating the redirect should include a meta http-equiv="refresh" tag, but set a high timeout.  
// This enables search engines to know, when parsing, that the page is redirected (in case it matters for SEO).
// That page should also include the manual version of Plausible's JS and finally include this file.
// This code calls Plausible to record the pageview, and registers a callback and performs the redirect.
// This ensures that the pageview is fully recorded before the refresh occurs.  If the refresh is simply inlined
// then, in FireFox, we've found that the pageview is not recorded.  We also add a 50 ms delay so that the browser
// can record a 202 for the POST (doesn't seem to be strictly required - we see the event is send to Plausible and,
// sometimes we get the 202 and other times we don't - likely just a timing issue).
window.plausible = window.plausible || function() { (window.plausible.q = window.plausible.q || []).push(arguments) };
redirect = async () => { 
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 50));
    window.location = document.querySelector( '[http-equiv="refresh"]' ).content.split( 'url=' )[1]; 
}
plausible("pageview", {callback: redirect})
```