# Confirm if google analytics is well implemented

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

**Intro:** I'm having a problem implementing google analytics in a website that is not mine and would like to correctly implement it and confirm without the need of waiting several hours untill google checks my website again.

**Main problem:** I copy pasted the script code to every page on the website (all html) but google isn't detecting it. I suspect the problem is in the first index.html on the root of the website but for now I must have it there so please don't tell me I have to remove this file. That is not the question.

**Code of index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script>
<!-- GOOGLE ANALYTICS PASTED CODE IS HERE -->
</script>
<!-- TITLE AND METADATA ARE HERE BUT NOT RELEVANT -->

<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.FAKEDOMAIN.com/Site/index.html">

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Extra info:** Google control not installed because it says it doesn't detectes the code on initial page. I think it is because the script might not be tottaly executed and then the page refreshs to another link and google will just consider that the script isn't installed on the initial page because the script wasn't tottaly run. Is there a way I can force the full execution before redirecting? Then a way to confirm with alerts if the data is being collected properly so that I am sure it is just a matter of time before google analytics control is properly installed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Google actually attempts to *detect* the code on your page.  Rather, the page runs and the script executes and pings some Google server to report the usage.  Once this usage gets reported, you'll start seeing activity in your Google account.  This might take a day or two.

I think you're right about the *meta refresh* though.  Once the meta tag is encountered, the browser will redirect and script on the page is not executed.  I would suggest removing the `<meta>` tag and redirecting with script, after the Google Analytics code is run:

```
<script>
  // GA code here
  location.href = 'http://www.FAKEDOMAIN.com/Site/index.html'; //Redirect here
</script>
```

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance but what is the difference of using it inside the script rather then meta? Isn't the code always executed line by line? In terms of flow it would be the same or not?

Comment: I think in theory, that's correct.  However, the GA code simply inserts another script which loads `ga.js` off a remote server, which does who knows what.  The page might be redirected before that happens.  Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205850/is-it-possible-to-run-javascript-code-before-meta-refresh) question which is similar.  You need to find a way to defer the redirect until after the GA script runs.

Comment: Nice. It is in fact a similar question. I will test this to see if GA correctly tracks the initial page. I can't vote up because I don't have enough rep :(